# How to avoid memory leak work handler every 5 minute on android?

Tags: memory-leaks

My app is a record camera preview app. It will make a new record file every 5 minutes.

After 20 seconds of creating the file, this handler will start:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/" +myFileName);

        long size = file.length();

        if (size == 0){
            if (file.delete()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "delete success");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "fail delete");
            }
        }
     }
  }, 20000);
}
```

I was wondering, if the handler would work every 5 minutes, would there be a memory leak?

If so, how could I avoid the memory leak to occur?

Comment: Are you saying a memory leak occurs, and that you need to find out how to fix it?  Or are you asking whether a leak will occur?

Comment: my question  whether a leak will occur.   when handler execute every 5 minute.

Comment: Why would you think it would leak memory if run at different intervals?